# Yaws SSL: Decode Error

Tags: ssl, erlang, yaws

I've tried running my yaws Web-server (on digital-ocean) by changing my webpage from http://XXX.XX.XX to https://XXX.XX.XX

on the Erlang shell, i get

```
SSL accept failed: {tls_alert, "decode error"}
```

the yaws.conf seems to come with a default key and certificate and i haven't made any modifications to that.

could i check what needs to be done to enable SSL? thanks much.

Comment: Can you maybe post some debug information, e.g.: `curl -v --trace-time --trace-ascii server1.log https://XXX.XX.XX`

Comment: It would also help to provide version information for both Yaws and Erlang, and also show your `yaws.conf`, especially the part for the server under which the error occurs.

Comment: Do the default key and cert actually exist? Or does the configuration mention some files as examples, but the files don't really exist?

Comment: @Amiramix thank you very much. I traced your steps and figured out that it was a problem with my openssl settings. Thereafter I followed the responses to other SO questions and solved it.

Comment: @SteveVinoski thank you for your response. I used the latest versions and example yaws.conf codes. Those were ok, the problem was with my openssl code as articulated above. The trace logs were immensely helpful.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot thanks. Yes the files really existed, but those were not tied to the particular server. So following the traces helped figure out what was wrong.

Comment: @user3847136: if there are other SO questions that answered your question, we should mark this as a duplicate of the best one of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion of Amiramix to check the trace via

curl -v --trace-time --trace-ascii server1.log https://XXX.XX.XX

solved the question.